# Consumer listener method throwing ClassCastException

Tags: json, serialization, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to fetch tweet from Twitter ( using Twitter4j Api) and sending them to kafka topic and then consumer is going to listen it and save it to database.
Tweets are reaching to Kafka topic but failing to convert message payload at consumer side.
error:

```
2021-06-23 18:06:03.725 ERROR 8456 --- [cListener-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler        : **Backoff none exhausted for twitter-topic-0@410**

org.springframework.kafka.listener.**ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void com.microservice.kafkaconsumer.Consumer.Impl.KafkaConsumerImple.receiveMessage(java.util.List<com.eventdriven.microservices.eventdrivenmicroservices.Model.TwitterModel>)' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.eventdriven.microservices.eventdrivenmicroservices.Model.TwitterModel (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.eventdriven.microservices.eventdrivenmicroservices.Model.TwitterModel is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2367) ~[spring-kafka-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
```

producer properties:

```
spring.kafka.producer:
    client-id: twitter-topic
    bootstrap-server: localhost:9092
    key-serializer : org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer
    value-serializer :  org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    properties:
        schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
```

Consumer Implementation

```
 @Service
 public class KafkaConsumerNewImpl {
            
  @Autowired
  private JsonTransformer jsonTransformer;
            
  @Autowired
  private TwitterRepository twitterRepository;
                
  @KafkaListener(id = "twitterTopicListener", topics="twitter-topic")
  public void receiveMessage(@Payload(required = false) List<TwitterModel> messages)                           
  {
     List<TwitterData> twitterData = jsonTransformer.conversion(messages);
            
      twitterRepository.saveAll(twitterData);
  }
    
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JsonTransformer {

    public List<TwitterData> conversion(List<TwitterModel> jsonModels) {

             return jsonModels.stream()
                .map(jsonModel -> TwitterData
                        .builder()
                        .id(jsonModel.getId())
                        .userName(jsonModel.getUserName())
                        .text(jsonModel.getText())
                        .build()

               ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

TwitterData

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TwitterData
{
    @Id
    @JsonProperty
    public Long id;

    @JsonProperty
    public String userName;

    @JsonProperty
    public String text; 
}
```

Twitter Model

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class TwitterModel 
{
    public Long id;
    public String userName;
    public String text;
}
```

Consumer properties

```
spring:
    kafka:
        consumer:
            enable-auto-commit: true
            auto-offset-reset: earliest
            bootstrap-server: localhost:9092

            properties:
                key-deserializer : org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
                value-deserializer : org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
                spring:
                    json:
                        trusted:
                            packages: "*"
```

I tried to debug the program.Control is reaching to the `JsonTransformer` but from `map(jsonModel->TwitterData` is jumping to last line and then throws exception.

Comment: Could you maybe add the whole message from the exception and also add your `pom.xml`? To see which versions you use.

Comment: @AlexP. I have added full exception. Actually , error is that much, but it is repeating many times. I think , message is getting stored so it is being tried many times. And I think  `Backoff none exhausted for twitter-topic` error is regarding that.  I have not set how many times , retry should be done.

Comment: @AlexP. another error are  `Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long]`   and `Failed to convert message payload`

Comment: @AlexP.  spring-boot 2.5.1 , java 11, spring-cloud- version = 2020.0.3

Comment: You receive messages from the twitter api, so `TwitterAvroModel` is not from twitter but your model. In your receiveMessage method try using Object instead. `public void receiveMessage(Long key, Object message)`. Try to debug it and check what fields you see.

Comment: To clarify, your **AvroProducer** works? You can use `kafka-avro-console-consumer` to test it?

Comment: @AlexP. I added jackson-databind dependency and seems that previous error gone but new one got. I debug the program and found the break point. But why that is happening I dont know. I have updated the question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Message is coming to topic but problem is at consumer listening method. I degug the program and found break point. I have updated question regarding that.

Comment: @tushar the exception kind of speaks for itself. Have you tried using Object or String instead and just see what comes in?

Comment: Your `conversion` method shouldn't compile because the method is expecting a `TwitterData`, but youre actually returning a List. And now that you're using JSON, you don't need the schema registry property

Comment: @AlexP. Yes, I  tried with Object. But gets error as `can not resolve method stream in Object` same for getId(), getUserName() and getText()

Comment: @OneCricketeer When I am accepting `conversion(List<TwitterModel> jsonModels)` I found in debugging, only 1 tweet data ( id,userName, text) appears there. But it is List then why not multiple data is comming there ? I tried with `conversion(TwitterModel jsonModels)` but still error. I tried to return `TwitterData` as well as  `List<TwitterData>` but still error. Can you explain conversion() ? I am really confused.

Comment: You should only expect one message at a time from `@KafkaListener`, so why are you trying to use lists at all? You've not shown your incoming messages, so are they a JSON array or not?

Comment: @OneCricketeer But in ` receiveMessage(@Payload(required = false) List<TwitterModel> messages)` multiple messages are comming and those messages,  I am passing for conversion and then for storage.

Comment: Have you read around this section of the doc about the `setMessageConverter` method? https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#messaging-message-conversion

Comment: _Multiple message are coming_. Yes, **one at a time**, though

Comment: You need to use a BatchListener to get a list - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#batch-listeners

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234125/discussion-between-tushar-and-onecricketeer).